# How to rename folders in Windows 7: command line that have spaces in the name

Tags: cmd, windows-7

How do I rename a path that has spaces in it under Windows 7?

Command line:

```
rename c:\ho hum\new folder  ->  c:\ho_hum\new_folder
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

This can only be done by moving the folder and set a new name for the destination:

```
move "c:\ho hum\new folder" "c:\ho hum\new_folder"
move "c:\ho hum" "c:\ho_hum"
```